# Centos 7 rsyslog not logging remote messages

Tags: rsyslog, centos7

I've setup a remote rsyslog server for testing but I can't seem to get it to log from a remote system.  I have an app on my desktop (windows) called "Syslog Test Message Utility 1.0" which sends test syslog messages on UDP 514.  I see the message appear on my Centos box on port 514 (using Wireshark interface) but no corresponding line appears in /var/log/messages as I would expect.

I've verified that the logging does work (e.g.. logger test) but just not from the remote system.  Here is my etc/rsyslog.conf file..

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
#$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log


# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
#$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
#$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g   # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
#$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
#$ActionQueueType LinkedList   # run asynchronously
#$ActionResumeRetryCount -1    # infinite retries if host is down
# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
# ### end of the forwarding rule ###
```

and I've verified that the host is listening on port 514 as expected

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15273/rsyslogd      
tcp6       0      0 :::514                  :::*                    LISTEN      15273/rsyslogd      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*                           15273/rsyslogd      
udp6       0      0 :::514                  :::*                                15273/rsyslogd
```

I'm just not even sure what to look for next.. I can't seem to figure out why my message coming from my Syslog app isn't creating a log entry in my messages file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that CentOS 7 (and I'm assuming RHEL 7) have a firewall other than iptables called firewalld.  After disabling this firewall in my dev environment I was able to successfully syslog to 514.

systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl status firewalld

Disabling the firewall is admittedly overkill, as I'm sure you can create a rule for 514, but since my server is in a lab...it was acceptable in my case.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped with my problem